# Toggle button with tailwindcss

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, toggle, vanillajs-datepicker

Hope you can assist, I am trying to make a toggle button with javascript and tailwindcss.
I was wondering if my javascript is proper, this way, as I have to write a else statement  to get it working and I am not sure if that is required with a toggle button.
Please see my html and javascript.

The date-picker-container class is the button, which needs to open the dates container on click of date-picker-container.

```
<div class="col-start-4 col-end-7 ... bg-slate-500">
            <div class="mb-6"> <!-- Date and Time Part -->
                Date
                <div class="date-time-container">

                    <div class="date-picker-container relative max-w-xs h-16 bg-red-400 cursor-pointer select-none">

                        <div class="selected-date w-full h-16 text-center flex items-center">16/7/2023</div>
                        
                        <div class="dates-container bg-lime-600 absolute w-full top-16 left-0 invisible">
                            <div class="month flex justify-between">
                                <div class="arrows prev-month">&lt;</div>
                                <div class="month-item">July 2023</div>
                                <div class="arrows next-month">&gt;</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="days=container"></div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    
                 </div>

            </div>

        </div>
```

and this is my javascript, is there a way to do this shorter or better?

```
  const date_picker_el = document.querySelector(".date-picker-container");
const days_el = document.querySelector(".dates-container");

function toggleDatePicker(e){
    if(days_el.classList.contains("invisible")){
    days_el.classList.remove("invisible");    
    days_el.classList.add("active:visible");
    }else{
    
    days_el.classList.remove("active:visible");
    days_el.classList.add("invisible");

    }
}

date_picker_el.addEventListener("click", toggleDatePicker);
```

Thank you for any help.

B.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply toggle the class.

```js
days_el.classList.toggle('invisible');
```

Comment: See the code working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/37waf84y/).